# What is the unit of duration in tcsendbreak()?

Tags: c, linux

From almost all the Linux manpages `termios(3)`:

> `tcsendbreak()` transmits a continuous stream of zero-valued bits for
>   a specific duration, if the terminal is using asynchronous serial data
>   transmission.  If duration is  zero,  it transmits  zero-valued  bits
>   for at least 0.25 seconds, and not more that 0.5 seconds. **If
>   duration is not zero, it sends zero-valued bits for some
>   implementation-defined length of time.**
>
> If  the terminal is not using asynchronous serial data transmission,
>   tcsendbreak() returns without taking any action.

So, what EXACTLY is the "some implementation-defined length of time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, it's milliseconds.

From the same manpage you're quoting from:

> The effect of a nonzero  ***duration***  with  tcsendbreak()  varies.   SunOS
>          specifies  a  break  of duration * N seconds, where N is at least 0.25,
>          and not more than 0.5.  **Linux**, AIX, DU, Tru64 send a break of ***duration*
>          milliseconds**.   FreeBSD and NetBSD and HP-UX and MacOS ignore the value
>          of duration.  Under Solaris and UnixWare,  tcsendbreak()  with  nonzero
>          duration behaves like tcdrain()

you can see the source [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/tcsendbrk.c;h=36ff933ccf2d6d986a15d797d34572f04da15c3d;hb=3ae3c4371df5a06d84096f9c6f7bfbe0d3c46a0d#l37).

It's calling `__ioctl (fd, TCSBRKP, (duration + 99) / 100);`, and `TCSBRKP` itself sends a break of `arg` tenths of second, as documented in the `tty_ioctl(4)` manpage.

Answer (score 0):

It means that on different systems, you may see different behavior; depending on how the implementation chooses to interpret the `duration` value.

Some more detail on that from man ioctl_tty(2):

> (SVr4, UnixWare, Solaris, Linux treat tcsendbreak(fd,arg) with
>                 nonzero arg like tcdrain(fd).  SunOS treats arg as a multi‐
>                 plier, and sends a stream of bits arg times as long as done
>                 for zero arg.  DG/UX and AIX treat arg (when nonzero) as a
>                 time interval measured in milliseconds.  HP-UX ignores arg.)

Answer (score 0):

First, what is an implementation?
It is a functional version (software running on a computer) of a description of a certain standard, or in this particular case, the description of a function. For example, GCC's C compiler **implements** the C standard. The GCC compiler software is the functional version of the C standard.

Next, what is implementation defined behavior?  Taking the example of C language again,

> it is unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made.

The implementations (different compilers in this case) are given certain freedom w.r.t to certain behaviors in the standard. One example given in the C standard is:

> An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right.

That means different compilers can decide differently as to what is to be done when a signed integer (whose leftmost bit is 1) is shifted right.

In case of `tcsendbreak` function, different implementations of this function can send zero-valued bits for lengths of time which can be different (in other words implementation-defined).